# What are the parameters for the Mediawiki template {{Special:RecentChanges}}

Tags: templates, mediawiki

For the Mediawiki template {{Special:RecentChanges}}, I know you can control the number of pages shown. If you wanted to show only the last 10 pages, the code would look like this:

```
{{Special:RecentChanges/10}}
```

Does anyone know if there are parameters other than the number of changes that can be used? For example, I'd like not display some of the links (e.g. contribs, block, rollback, etc.).

I can't find any documentation anywhere.

Comment: `Special:RecentChanages` is not actually a template, it's a [transclusion of special page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Transclusion#Special_pages).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additional parameters may be used in a comma separated list such as:

```
{{Special:RecentChanges/days=5,limit=40}}
```

- days
- limit
- hidebots
- bots
- hideminor
- minor
- hideliu
- hidepatrolled
- hideanons
- hidemyself

More http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Recent_changes